# What will happen if I implement ThreadLocal in a factory class

Tags: java, multithreading, static, factory, thread-local

I'm trying to implement formatters for date and numbers in Java. But some of Formatters in java are not thread safe, eg. `DecimalFormat, SimpleDateFormat`!(First of all, I don't understand why they are not threadsafe like `DateTimeFormat`!) So, after searching a bit, I came across `ThreadLocal` variables.

All the snippets I've ever seen about `ThreadLocal`, they use `final`. Of course it does make sense to have one instance of formatter. But, lets say we need one formatter but for 3 patterns.

**FormatFactory.java**

```
public class FormatFactory {
  public static ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat> getMoneyFormatter(final String pattern) {
    return new ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat>() {
      @Override
      public DecimalFormat initialValue() {
        DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        if (!pattern.equals(FormatPatterns.MT940_DECIMAL)) {
          symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        }
        decFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        decFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        return decFormat;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Format.java**

```
public static String money(BigDecimal amount, String pattern) {
  return FormatFactory.getMoneyFormatter(pattern).get().format(amount);
}
```

**Usage**

```
Format.money(balance, FormatPatterns.MT940_DECIMAL)
Format.money(balance, FormatPatterns.SIGNED_MONEY)
Format.money(balance, FormatPatterns.MONEY)
```

Is it still thread safe in this usage???

**UPDATE:**

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655070/1507556) has solved my problem.

My snippet is as in below:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat>> decimialFormatsByPattern = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat>>();

public static DecimalFormat getMoneyFormatter(final String pattern) {
    ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat> decimalFormatter = decimialFormatsByPattern.get(pattern);
    if (decimalFormatter == null) {
      decimalFormatter = new ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat>() {
        @Override
        public DecimalFormat initialValue() {
          DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
          DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
          symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
          if (!pattern.equals(FormatPatterns.MT940_DECIMAL)) {
            symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
          }
          decFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
          decFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
          return decFormat;
        }
      };
      decimialFormatsByPattern.putIfAbsent(pattern, decimalFormatter);
    }

    return decimalFormatter.get();
  }
```

**Usage**

```
public static String money(BigDecimal amount, String pattern) {
    return FormatFactory.getMoneyFormatter(pattern).format(amount);
  }
```

Comment: Kayaman said, "...resource leaks."  If some thread, t, creates a DecimalFormat instance (or any other object) and sticks it in a ThreadLocal object, the ThreadLocal object will continue to hold the reference even after thread t dies.  The object created by thread t will never be garbage collected.  ThreadLocal is good to use when you have a fixed set of threads, but it can lead to trouble in an application that continually creates new short-lived threads.  (Note: Some ExecutorService implementations create and destroy threads as the backlog in the request queue changes.)

Answer (score 2):

Now you're returning a new `ThreadLocal` every time `getMoneyFormatter` is being called. You should initialize it once only.

However, using `ThreadLocal` can result in resource leaks, so unless you really know you'll need it, it would be simpler to just create a new formatter when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be thread-safe  because in getMoneyFormatter method you are creating a spearate instance of ThreadLocal on each call of getMoneyFormatter method.

But this is not the correct use of ThreadLocal.You should initialize it once only and it should be used where you want to store variable specific to some thread and then the same thread can later on fetch the value from ThreadLocal. Stored value in ThreadLocal is only visible to that thread no other thread can modify or change it.

In your scenario if DecimalFormat will be a local object of method getMoneyFormatter then also it will be thread safe in that case you don't need ThreadLocal.Please check the below example.

```
  public DecimalFormat getMoneyFormatter(final String pattern) {

        DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        if (!pattern.equals(FormatPatterns.MT940_DECIMAL)) {
          symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        }
        decFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        decFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
        return decFormat

  }



  public static String money(BigDecimal amount, String pattern) {
      return FormatFactory.getMoneyFormatter(pattern).format(amount);
    }
```

Comment: It will be several threads in the project that I'm working currently. So DecimalFormat has to be made thread-safe with ThreadLocal.